# How To Get List Of DropDown Menu Items of webbrowser?

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I'm creating an application in which I need to get a list of all the elements of the drop-down menu. I'm programming in Visual Basic Express 2010, and I have webbrowser1 on my form. The webpage has a drop-down menu like below:

```
<select name="abc" id="def">
  <option value="1">Element 1</option>
  <option value="2">Element 2</option>
  <option value="3">Element 3</option>
</select>
```

I would like to get elements of the drop-down menu to an array.

Comment: You can use GetElementById then loop over it's children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the CruleD 's solution：

```
Private Sub getOption()

    Dim optionList as new List(Of String)

    For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("def").Children

        optionList.Add(element.InnerHtml)

    Next

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", optionList.ToArray))

End Sub
```

In Output window it will show：

Element 1,Element 2,Element 3

If you want to convert the list to array：

```
Dim myArray As String() = optionList.ToArray
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = $("select#def");

var valueArray = _.map(options ,function(option) {
    return option.value;
});
```

use Underscore.js _.map method to return values to an Array